# Roles Discord.js (Printing roles on a embed)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I want to make a little user profile, but I want it to print out the users roles. Is it possible?

```
  case "Profile":
  var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
     .addField(message.author.username, "Roles: " + [How would I put the users roles here?]) // user, roles
     .addField("Stats", "XP: 0/100 Level 0") // XP, Level?
     .setColor(0x00ffff)
     .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL)
  message.channel.sendEmbed(embed);
  console.log(message.author + ` Viewed their profile!`)
  break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `message.member.roles`, also known as the ["Guild Member Roles"](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=roles)

So your code could look something like this:

```
  case "Profile":
  var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
     .addField(message.author.username, "Roles: " + message.member.roles.map(role => role.name).join(", ")) // user, roles
     .addField("Stats", "XP: 0/100 Level 0") // XP, Level?
     .setColor(0x00ffff)
     .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL)
  message.channel.sendEmbed(embed);
  console.log(message.author + ` Viewed their profile!`)
  break;
```

Keep in mind that this code will only work for messages that are received in a guild channel (as opposed to a direct message query), so make sure to handle any other scenarios accordingly. :-)

Comment: You're welcome, mind accepting the answer if it solved your problem? ;)

Answer (score 0):

The code is pretty much the RichEmbed. You have set it and just need to configure it with the image if you just got it from here.

```
case "Profile":
  var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
     .addField(message.author.username, "Roles: " + message.member.roles.map(role => role.name).join(", ")) // user, roles
     .addField("Stats", "XP: 0/100 Level 0") // XP, Level?
     .setColor(0x00ffff)
     .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL)
  message.channel.sendEmbed(embed);
  console.log(message.author + ` Viewed their profile!`)
  break;
```